# equals not possible for class?

Tags: java, equals

In Java, I have a function with a signature, where a Type is passed in:

```
public Object convert(Object object, Type type) {
}
```

Inside the function, I want to determine if Type is String, but when I do this

```
String.class.equals(type.getClass())
```

Android Studio is telling me `'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'Class<capture of ? extends Type>' and 'Class<String>'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can `Type` ever by a string?  you meant to check `object` maybe?

Comment: If (s instanceof String)

Comment: Am I right in thinking "object" is not necessarily of type "Type"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a javac error — it's something your IDE is providing as a warning (or error, depending on your setting).

That said, in this case the warning is a useful one. You're asking if the class object returned by `type.getClass()` is equal to the class object represented by the literal `String.class`. Given that `Type` is not a superclass of `String`, I can tell you right now that the answer is false: the `Type` class is not the same as the `String` class. Your IDE is trying to tell you the same.

If what you're trying to figure out is whether type *instance* of `type` represents the String class, then you don't need the `getClass()`:

```
String.class.equals(type)
```

Comment: Good answer, although I think == will do instead of equals().

Comment: It will, and in cases like this it's largely a matter of style/preference/habits. Many people (me included) prefer to use `.equals` for objects and `==` for primitives, even if they know that the implementation of `equals` just defers to the default `==`. (The big exception to this is enums, which are objects but often checked using `==` -- but they're odd in other respects, too, like being used in switch statements.)

Comment: hmm... In general, `Foo<A>.equals(Foo<B>)` can legitimately return true even if `A!=B`. But `Foo<A>==Foo<B>` will not compile because no object can be both types. Not sure what the IDE is doing there. Maybe it sees that `equals()` is not overridden therefore equivalent to `==`

Comment: Well, even JLS has code samples that compare Classes with `==`. It seems very certain that a `class` has only one `Class` instance.

Comment: `String.class.equals(type)` was exactly what I had at first, but my IDE told me this `'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'Type' and 'Class<String>'` so I thought I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

type.getClass() does not return the Class represented by type, but the Class *of* type (which will be the .class of one of the implementations of Type). In other words if "Type" is a Class, then type.getClass() will return the Class object for "Class".

What you need is:

```
if (type == String.class) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `instanceof` on the object rather then the type, replace:

```
String.class.equals(type.getClass())
```

by:

```
if(object instanceof String) {
   // do something
}
```

The instance of Type in the method signature is not needed for your purpose.

Comment: I don't believe "object" is necessarily of type "type". I believe the point of the method is to convert "object" into an object of type "type".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate that certain object is a string then you can use a method like this one:

```
public boolean isStringInstance(Object o) {
    return o instanceof String;
}
```

So if you run the next code lines:

```
isStringInstance(new Type());
isStringInstance(new String());
```

You will get:

false

true

Comment: I think "Type" is intended to be "java.lang.reflect.Type", which is an interface.

Comment: If that is the case, then it can be solved replacing the method using:
public boolean isStringInstance(Type t) {
return t == String.class;}